# How to use subreport variable in main report

Tags: jasper-reports

I have some issue with *subreport* which has values like:

A   B   C
1   5   3

A,B,C are header and 1,5,3 are row data

I need this field data in my main report so that i can additionally make some calculation in my master report.

How is this possible?

I read a lot articles and I found that it can be done by **return values** property.

But this property only display default variable of page number,column count etc but not the datafield of *subreport*.

So how to return the actual field values to main report?

Answer (score 0):

you must create a Parameter in you Base report to store the "return value" from your sub-report into.